# Generalizing Steinitz's theorem on ACFs

Tags: logic, field-theory, model-theory

Steinitz's theorem on the *existence* of an algebraically closed extension of every field clearly generalizes to broader model-theoretic contexts (existentially closed structures).

But there is another half to Steinitz's theorem that I had not thought about, which is the uniqueness of the algebraic closure of a field.  I believe that it comes from the uniqueness of the splitting field extension of a field and a polynomial.  Does this generalize to other contexts?  That is: given an AE theory $T$ and $M \models T$, parameters $\overline a$ in $M$, a p.p. formula $\phi(\overline x, y)$ such that $T \cup \operatorname{Diag}(A) \cup \{\phi(\overline a, y)\}$ is consistent, does there exist a unique and minimal extension of $A'$ realizing $\phi(\overline a, y)$?

I'm guessing not, but unable to come up with an actual example.  A bonus would be where $T$ is the AE theory of some structure, in which case there seems little room to maneuver.

Comment: The "splitting field" in Steinitz's theorem isn't really analogous to "realizing a formula" in your question. In the case of fields, the formula $\phi(x,y)$ could say that $f(y)g(y)=0$ for two irreducible polynomials $f,g$. Then there would be two minimal extensions realizing $\phi(a,y)$.

Comment: It should be extremely rare that we have an analogue of the splitting field. But in order to make this precise, can you clarify what you mean by "unique and minimal"? Usually, we would say $M$ is minimal over a set $A$ if $M$ has no proper elementary substructure containing $A$. I think a better generalization of the properties of splitting fields might be primeness: $M$ is prime over $A$ if every embedding of $A$ into a model extends to an elementary embedding of $N$.